# Survival functions

Tags: distributions, survival, hazard

Let me explain my question. Consider, for example, a Weibull mortality curve with covariates included:

$$\mu_{x}=\bigg(\frac{a}{b}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{x}{b}\bigg)^{a-1}\text{exp}(\beta Z)\quad\quad a,b,x>0$$

where $\beta$ is a $(1\times n)$ matrix and $Z$ is an $(n\times 1)$ matrix. We can derive the cumulative hazard function as follows:

$$\begin{align}
H_{x}(t)&=\int_{0}^{t}\mu_{x+t}\,dt\\
&=\bigg(\frac{a}{b}\bigg)\text{exp}(\beta Z)\int_{0}^{t}\bigg(\frac{x+t}{b}\bigg)^{a-1}\,dt\\
&=a\,\text{exp}(\beta Z)\bigg[\bigg(\frac{x+t}{b}\bigg)^{a}\bigg]^{t}_{0}\\
&=\frac{a\,\text{exp}(\beta Z)}{b^{a}}\big((x+t)^{a}-x^{a}\big)
\end{align}$$

From here the survival curve is:

$$\begin{align}
S_{x}(t)&=\text{exp}(-H_{x}(t))\\
&=\frac{\text{exp}\Big(-\frac{a\,\text{exp}(\beta Z)}{b^{a}}(x+t)^{a}\Big)}{\text{exp}\Big(-\frac{a\,\text{exp}(\beta Z)}{b^{a}}x^{a}\Big)}\\
&=\frac{\text{exp}\Big(-H_{0}(x+t)\Big)}{\text{exp}\Big(-H_{0}(x)\Big)}\\
&=\frac{S_{0}(x+t)}{S_{0}(x)}
\end{align}$$

So in general is it true that:

$$S_{0}(x+t)=S_{0}(x)S_{x}(t)$$

i.e. surviving from $0$ to $(x+t)$ is equivalent to surviving from $0$ to $x$ and then surviving $t$ from $x$? It seems intuitive and is probably very obvious but I just wanted to make sure my understanding is sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any distribution assumption.

With your notation, 
$$H_x(t) = \int_0^t \mu_{x+s}ds = \int_x^{t+x}\mu_sds$$
is the cumulative hazard between $x$ and $t+x$ and then
$$
S_x(t) = e^{-H_x(t)} 
$$
is the probability of surviving up to time $t + x$ **given that the individual is alive at $x$**, i.e.
$$
S_x(t) = P(T>x+t|T>x) 
$$
and by simple probability theory, this is 
$$
P(T>x+t|T>x)  = \frac{P(T>x+t)}{P(T>x)}.
$$

I think it's more clear to see why this is true if you keep in mind that, with your notation, $S_x(t)$ refers to a conditional probability (which I made explicit here).